# Como creo un metodo en mongo db para eliminr un determinado texto y cambiar el valor del campo

Tags: json, mongodb

Buenas tardes me enceuntro trabjando en una base MongoDB y no puedo crear un metodo para quedarme con la parte numerica y eliminar el texto y a su vez pase de String a Decimal.

Agradezco su ayuda

Latitud:"0 deg 10' 54.00" S"

Longitud:"78 deg 30' 21.00" W"

Altitud:"9.6 m Above Sea Level"

Circulacion:"Impar"

Distancia:"0.21km al Sur"

Tengo alrededor de 2000 datos diferentes pero solo necesito que en el campo Altitud se quede el valor numerico y el tipo cambie de string a Decimal.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Por favor para que los usuarios te puedan ayudar mejor, comparte lo que has intentado hasta el momento junto con un código o consulta

Comment: @Fabricio con respecto a tu pregunta es para guardarlo en un nuevo documento o solo quieres visualizar el resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que hacer una query para obtener todos los datos que desees modificar y luego irlos cambiando con un [foreach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) de acuerdo a lo que necesites.

```javascript
db.collection.find().forEach(
    function(e, i) {
        // Esto es suponiendo que todas las unidades están en metros
        // Si tuvieras unidades como km, millas, etc. 
        // tendrías que hacer la conversión... Pero eso es lo de menos
        e.Altitud = parseFloat(e.Altitud.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
        db.collection.save(e);
    }
);
```

**EDIT:** Leí mal pero de todos modos lo dejo por si te puede ayudar

```javascript
db.collection.find().forEach(
    function(e, i) {
        let temp = e.Latitud.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, " ").trim();
        temp = temp.split(' ');
        e.Latitud = parseInt(temp[0]) + parseFloat(temp[1] / 60) + parseFloat(temp[2] / 3600);
        db.collection.save(e);
    }
);
```

Ya lo demás es muy parecido

Comment: Realmente no sé si haya una mejor solución que esté más optimizada, pero espero te pueda ayudar. Lo probé brevemente en mi computadora y funcionó correctamente. Si acaso lo que tendrías que hacer es agregar una condición `if (!isNaN(e.Altitud)) continue;`